# Brooklyn theme for shopify

Tags: image, slider, shopify, product

I'm currently subscribed to Shopify and am using the "Brooklyn" theme. I would essentially like to have the images appearing on the product pages to be in slideshow format instead of them appearing one below the other since scrolling down in order to see all the images can be tedious. Anyone have experience with this theme that can give me a hand? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is explained in the answer by "Helpful Human" in this link. 
https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/change-product-photos-to-thumbnails-under-main-image-in-brooklyn-theme-272292

I followed this to modify my Brooklyn theme to modify the products. There are certain modification to be done.

1. Install the Classic Theme (but do not publish) from your shop admin.
2. Go to Online Store > Themes > and click Edit HTML/CSS under the Classic Theme dropdown
3. Open the Assets folder and click on the `timber.js.liquid` file.
4. In a separate tab open the HTML/CSS of Brooklyn theme. (Please take a backup before you attempt this) and edit the 'theme.js.liquid' file of Brooklyn theme
5. In Class theme timber.js, you'll see a line with code timber.productImageSwitch(); in the init function. This is the feature we need. Copy and paste this line into the same timber.init function in your theme.js file
6. You'll also need to copy over the actual function code that is further down the file (around lines 175 - 207). To make sure you're grabbing the correct code, search the page (cmd+F) for productImageSwitch and you'll see the related function as well as the switchImage function. Copy and past both of these functions in their entirety into the theme.js.
7. Now in theme.js file(Brooklyn theme), find the line

   `Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImg, el, theme.showVariantImage);`

Replace this line with 
    `Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImg, el, timber.switchImage);`

1. The last piece of JS you'll want to copy is around lines 23 and 27 under the Product Page comment inside timber.cache. Copy both the lines below from timber.js(Classic) to theme.js(Brooklyn)
   `$productImageWrap: $('#ProductPhoto'),`
   `$thumbImages: $('#ProductThumbs').find('a.product-single__thumbnail'),`
   Note: Mind the trailing commas.
2. Lastly, you'll want to copy the markup from the product.liquid template related to the thumbnails. This begins with "{% if product.images.size > 1 %}"  and the related "{% endif %}" statement .
3. That's it. You can style the markup how you like but clicking the images should now swap the featured image without refreshing the page. If it doesn't work, check your browser's console for errors. With copy and pasting code, it's quite esay to miss a necessary comma or closing tag that can break the entire feature. This requires attention to detail.

Give a link to your shop in case you need further help.